# VTK: How should I generate threshold render from a structured grid

Tags: python, vtk

I would like to render scalar data on a structured grid that pass a certain threshold (for example, see below)

[image: an example of the kind of rendering I'd like, generated with paraview]

I have tried with vtk. See the following snippet below for my code

```
 grid.SetPoints(points)                                                         
 grid.SetDimensions(nx,ny,nz)                                                   
 grid.GetPointData().SetScalars(scalars)                                        
                                                                                
 threshold = vtk.vtkThresholdPoints()                                           
 threshold.SetInputData(grid)                                                   
 threshold.ThresholdByUpper(0.5)                                                
                                                                                
 mapper = vtk.vtkDataSetMapper()                                                
 mapper.SetInputConnection(threshold.GetOutputPort())                           
                                                                                
 actor = vtk.vtkActor()                                                         
 actor.SetMapper(mapper)                                                        
 renderer.AddActor(actor)                                                       
                                                                                
 interactor.Start()
```

I.e. I have a structured grid  with points and scalars set. I then build a threshold mapper and actor. The threshold looks like its working insofar as the correct subset is being singled out. But instead of an array of cubes it generates an array of dots (see below).

[image: my own render produces a series of dots as opposed to cubes]

My question: How can I replace these dots with cubes as they are shown in the first figure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vtkThreshold` instead of `vtkThresholdPoints`.

As you want cubes, you need topology to be preserved. The `points` version extract only points, so it breaks the cells information.